# Extracting values from a file keyed by multiple keys

Tags: bash, command-line, text-processing, sed, awk

Consider a file with `key=value` pairs, and each `key` is optionally a concatenation of multiple `key`s. In other words, many `key`s can map to one `value`. The reason behind this is that each `key` is a relatively short word compared to the length of the `value`, hence the data is being 'compressed' into lesser lines.

Illustration (i.e. not the real values):

```
$ cat testfile
AA,BB,CC=a-lengthy-value
A,B,C=a-very-long-value
D,E,F=another-very-long-value
K1,K2,K3=many-many-more
Z=more-long-value
```

It is valid to assume that all `key`s are unique, and will not contain the following characters:

- `key` delimiter: `,`
- key-value delimiter: `=`
- whitespace character:

`key`s may come in any form in the *future* (with the above constraints), they *currently* adhere to the following regex coincidentally: `[[:upper:]]{2}[[:upper:]0-9]`. Likewise, `value`s will not contain `=`, so `=` can be safely used to split each line. There are no multi-line `key`s or `value`s, so it is also safe to process line-by-line.

In order to facilitate data extraction from this file, a function `getval()` is defined as such:

```
getval() {
    sed -n "/^\([^,]*,\)*$1\(,[^=]*\)*=\(.*\)$/{s//\3/p;q}" testfile
}
```

As such, calling `getval A` will return the value `a-very-long-value`, not `a-lengthy-value`. It should also return nothing for a non-existent `key`.

**Questions:**

- Is the current definition of `getval()` robust enough?
- Are there alternative ways of performing the data extraction that are possibly shorter/more expressive/more restrictive?

For what it's worth, this script will run with cygwin's `bash` and `coreutils` that comes with it. Portability is not required here as a result (i.e. only brownie points will be given). Thanks!

**edit:**

Corrected function, added clarification about the keys.

**edit 2:**

Added clarification about the format (no multi-lines) and portability (not a requirement).

Comment: @mikeserv `$1` should be the key to search for, e.g. `A`

Comment: Well, in the example, `A` will only map to `a-very-long-value`. There can be lines like `AA,BB,CC=a-lengthy-value` but that should not be a match, because the key to search for is `A` and not `AA`.

Comment: @mikeserv yups. A comma will always be followed by another key. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it in much more readable form using `awk`:

```
getval() {
    awk -F'=' '$1~/\<'"$1"'\>/{print $2}' testfile
}
```

Comment: I made a significant change to `getval()` after your posting to fix a bug, as such I'm afraid this is not what I'm looking for. Could you update your answer if possible? Thanks! :) `getval()` looks right and I don't think I'll update it any further.

Comment: That looks okay to me, but you could mark the start of the match using `(^|,)`, to avoid partial matches.

Comment: @muru Good point! I only took care of substring at the end of the key with `[,=]`, forgot to do the same at the beginning. Thanks.

Comment: This is quite close, but fails for `K3` in the example. :(

Comment: @h.j.k. OK see the update, hopefully the last one. I changed pattern match beginning `\<` and end of the word `\>`.

Comment: Good, this is perfect. :) Now I learn about word matching in `gawk`, and coincidentally the definition "[a sequence of one or more letters, digits, or underscores](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html)" fits my use case.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`...

```
getval() { sed "/^\([^=]*,\)*$1[,=]/!d;s/.*=//;q"; } <infile
```

You might want to work on validating `$1` as input though.

Or with GNU `grep` and `cut`:

```
getval() { grep -Em1 "^([^=]*,)*$1[,=]" | cut -d= -f2-; } <infile
```

Comment: yeah. Definitely brownie points over the `gawk`-specific solution provided by @jimmij.

Comment: @h.j.k. - well, in fairness, most of my first ideas sucked. But then I took your `\(subexpression\)*` and jimmij's `[,=]` alternation and put them together ok.